# Use cql_filter with several parameters

Tags: geoserver, wfs, getfeature

I retrieve a specific feature from my WFS Layer with a GetFeature request:

```
request=GetFeature&cql_filter=myattr1=x&
```

Now, I want to filter for two attributes, thus, I make:

```
request=GetFeature&cql_filter=myattr1=x;myattr2=y&
```

However, what I get now is:

```
<ows:ExceptionText>
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
Index: 0, Size: 0
</ows:ExceptionText>
```

There must be a syntax error. Where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should say:

```
myattr1=x and myattr2=y
```

see the [ECQL spec](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/filter/ecql_reference.html#filter-ecql-reference) for the full syntax reference.